# Open new process from a java application which is started by a windows service

Tags: c#, java

I'm having a java application which opens the notepad.exe using, Runtime.getRuntime().exec().

And I want to run this application as a windows service. So I created a windows service using C#.

and I could successfully installed the service using 'installutil' command.

But although my java application started properly by the windows service, it does not open the notepad.exe.

I thought the problem is where the service is run as a SYSTEM process but not as the current login user. So I installed the service under the current user, by giving user credentials in installutil command.

Then the service and the java application properly started under the current user and I could see notepad.exe also created under the same user. But notepad is not visible.

Can anyone guide what has happened here please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's being started in another context.

In service options try checking the "Local System account" radio button, and then checking the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it shows my java application in cmd prompt.

Comment: It pops up a  'Interactive Service Detection' message box and tells 'A programming running on this computer is trying to display a message' and once click on the view message, it displays my java application runing on a console.

Comment: Found the reason for this problem, http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx

Comment: @Kelum glad to hear you sorted it out :) Good luck

Comment: Actually, I found the reason for my problem. but the issue is still exist :) I have to look some other way :) Thanks for the help anima.